# Require 2FA outside of Company range

Tags: authentication, two-factor-authentication

We have been looking at a way to make users authenticate via MFA outside of the company's network range?  I was looking at https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hdMQAAY, however, it doesn't seem to be able.  Is there a way to use trusted IP ranges in combination with high assurance logins? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible via a custom login flow. SF has a [samples package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm) that contains an example of conditional 2-factor flow based on IP range.

Comment: That sample package is configured to require users to manually enter a TOTP.  I'm trying to find a way to leverage the one-tap push notification from the Salesforce Authenticator app, but only for un-trusted IP logins. Any ideas??

Comment: @BrentBow Post a new question, please